# Magento 2 Join Product Collection with Custom CollectionFactory

Tags: collection, product-collection, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I have Custom Model Collection (followed [this tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html)).

In that I want to add the Product Collection into this custom collection by default. How to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please add your code what you have tried before?

Comment: Same as the tutorial I referred here. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

Comment: @SaravananDS Plz give brief detail what you actually want? where you want to add/embed Or you want standalone product object in model/block ? You question is totally confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can override

> Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection class and join your custom collection with using **_initSelect()** function

Example:

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    $this->getSelect()->joinRight(['secondTable' => $this->getTable('custom_table')],'secondTable.id = main_table.entity_id');
    return $this;
}
```